# Non-Blocking read from standard I/O in C#

Tags: c#, console-application, nonblocking

I want a non-blocking read function from console. How do I write that in C#?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Isn't ReadKey blocking?

Comment: @Mitch you need to combine at least `KeyAvailable` and `ReadKey`. And I'm still not sure if that's the right thing to do, and how it interacts with redirected input or dead keys. So it's certainly not a trivial question.

Comment: @Masoud Have you read, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738731/feed-input-to-console-readkey? It might be you are asking the wrong question for your problem...

Comment: What do you want to use that non blocking read for? The correct way to solve this might depend on those additional details.

Comment: Who said the OP asked about reading console input? “Non-blocking read” is a very broad topic. The quality of the question is similar to “I want a program for sending email.” Hence “not a real question” is IMO the best category for closing it.

Comment: @Ondrej To quote the OP: "from console"

Comment: @CodeInChaos “from console” can easily mean “from a console application”. IMO the question is highly indeterminate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var buf=new byte[2048];
var inputStream=Console.OpenStandardInput(); //dispose me when you're done
inputStream.BeginRead(buf,0,buf.Length,ar=>{
    int amtRead=inputStream.EndRead(ar);
    //buf has what you need. You'll need to decode it though
},null);
```

Comment: Didn't you forget the count parameter?

Comment: When will your `EndRead` be triggered? I think only if you arrive either at the end of the stream, or when the buffer is full, and not if only a few characters of input are available.

Comment: Ah. You are sort of right. Actually, the stream seems to be flushed only on carriage return. Your method is looking better and better!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (hangs) if there's nothing to read.
Blocking.

Answer (score 80):

[Richard Dutton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525138/richard) has a solution on [his blog](http://www.dutton.me.uk/2009/02/24/non-blocking-keyboard-input-in-c/):

```
while (true)  
{  
    if (Console.KeyAvailable)  
    {  
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);  
        switch (key.Key)  
        {  
            case ConsoleKey.F1:  
                Console.WriteLine("You pressed F1!");  
                break;  
            default:  
                break;  
        }  
    }  
    // Do something more useful  
}
```

Comment: the `ConsoleKeyInfo` contains the field `KeyChar` which represents the `char` representation, which might be what the OP wants.

Comment: @spender That's why there is the `// Do something more useful` comment in there.

Comment: This answer is perfect for what I wanted. I have a program running an infinite loop and outputting stuff, but I want to be able able to input commands via keyboard characters without blocking the loop.

Comment: I think this is the real answer the OP was searching for, and probably the one that should be marked as correct. In any case, it did what I was searching for. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't actually read from stdin when it's not Console!

Comment: Link to Blog is dead

Comment: I'm working with a redirected standard input, and as of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7373154/613014 and my experiences, ReadKey does not do what the heading of the question asks for - reading standard input.