# How redirect StandardInput on Process without process immediately exiting?

Tags: c#, redirect, process

I created a utility to lock files `lockfile.exe`, which accepts two parameters: *fileName* (file to be locked) and *fileShare* (share to be applied). I then call this utility from within another application to test error conditions when processing locked files. The `lockfile.exe` utility locks a file with the specified share and then waits for any character input to release the lock and exit.

In my test application I created a class `FileLocker` with two methods `LockFile` and `UnlockFile` as follows:

```
public class FileLocker
{
    private Process process;

    public void LockFile(string fileName)
    {
        this.process = new Process();
        this.process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        this.process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        this.process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        this.process.StartInfo.FileName = "lockfile.exe";
        this.process.StartInfo.Arguments =
            "\"" + fileName + "\" " + FileShare.Read.ToString();
        this.process.Start();
    }

    public void UnlockFile()
    {
        this.process.StandardInput.Write('X');
        this.process.StandardInput.Flush();
        this.process.WaitForExit();
        this.process.Close();
    }
}
```

When I call the method `LockFile` the process immediately exits after starting. It does not wait for the input in `UnlockFile`. When I do not redirect the standard input, then the process waits for keyboard input.

What do I need to change/fix, so that the process does not immediately exit. I need it to wait for the input provided in `UnlockFile` and only then should the process exit?

**Update:**

Updated to show `FileLocker` class above and to provide sample calls below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileLocker locker = new FileLocker();
        locker.LockFile("HelloWorld.txt");
        locker.UnlockFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the `LockFile` and `UnlockFile` methods.

Comment: I tested your program with a LockFile.exe that just contained a simple Console.ReadLine(), and it works just as expected if I change the Write('X') call to a WriteLine("X"). So I'm suspecting your problem is in the lockfile.exe program rather than this one. How are you waiting for a keypress (or input) in LockFile.exe? (Note that Console.ReadKey() will likely not work since it does not go through standard input stream to detect input)

Comment: If you want to lock a file, why don't you do that? No need for external process. That just makes life hard and the application brittle.

Comment: @DeCaf: Revising lockfile.exe to look for a Console.ReadLine() as opposed to a Console.ReadKey() and revising the calling code appropriately fixed the issue. If you post an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @David: I am creating a testing app that needs to simulate test real-life conditions where external processes may lock files that need to be accessed. That is why I am using an external executable to lock the file.

Comment: David is quite right, Windows doesn't care what process has the file locked.  Just open the file directly.  And yes, you can lock yourself out as well.  Locks are owned by the file handle, not the process.

Comment: Thanks David and Hans for the tip. I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are using `Console.ReadKey()` in your lockfile.exe application. This does not accept input from standard input but uses low-level keyboard hooks to check for key presses which you cannot send from another application.

I tested your program with a LockFile.exe that just contained a simple `Console.ReadLine()`, and it works just as expected if I change the `Write('X')` call to a `WriteLine("X")` (since the call to readline needs a newline before returning). So I'm suspecting your problem is in the lockfile.exe program rather than this one. Ensure you are using `Console.ReadLine()` to wait for input from standard input in your lockfile.exe application.

Comment: Over 10 years old and still saved my life. I additionally had the problem that the child process I wanted to redirect the standard input of (that used to called ReadKey) always vanished after starting if I did so. Do you have an idea why (in case you're still around)?

Comment: No idea without more information unfortunately.  But glad I could help... ten years ago. :D